# How to remove characters only near letters or numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove the characters `<`  only at the letters and numbers, if there are no numbers or letters keep `<` symbol.

```
/<  
<apple
<organes
<\
```

Transform to

```
    /<  
    apple
    organes
    <\
```

Comment: Search for `<(?![\W_])` and replace with nothing. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/lNumER/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find this:

`<(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])(.*)`

then replace with `$1` (this is 'space' followed by '$1').

Answer (score 0):

```
Search:  \b[<>]|[<>]\b
Replace:
```

This will replace any `<` or `>` "at the start or end of a word" (that's what `\b` means).

Comment: FIO, this also matches `<` in `<_`.

Answer (score 0):

Find what: `<(?=\w+)`
Replace with: `nothing`